# django TypedChoiceField - not allow default value of 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-forms, django-templates, parsley.js

I am not so sure I have designed my forms.py file correctly, when it comes to a TypedChoiceField and not allowing a selected value of "0" to be entered by the user.

I have read the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.TypedChoiceField), but couldn't find anything about this. There is something about empty_value, but I couldn't find any examples about this for the TypedChoiceField.

I have a list of country names in a select list:

```
<select data-parsley-required="true" name="address_country_style_type" data-parsley-required-message="This field is required." id="id_address_country_style_type" data-parsley-id="1440" class="input-xxlarge" data-original-title="" title="">
    <option value="0"> Select a country or territory</option>
    <option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="2">Aland Islands</option>
    <option value="3">Albania</option>
    ......
</select>
```

In my forms.py file I have the following (including the cleaned data code):

```
@parsleyfy
class AddressDetailsForm(forms.Form):

required_css_class = 'required'

address_country_style_type = forms.TypedChoiceField(
    coerce=int,
    label=_('Address Format'),
    choices=[(x, x) for x in range(0, 256)],
    required=True)
....

def clean(self):

    cd_addf = super(AddressDetailsForm, self).clean()

    if 'address_country_style_type' in cd_addf and cd_addf['address_country_style_type'] == 0:

        self._errors['address_country_style_type'] = self.error_class([_("You must select an Address Format.")])
        del self.cleaned_data['address_country_style_type']

    else:
        ....
```

I have added [django-parsley](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fagiliq%2FDjango-parsley&ei=gZbxU8zGNNfs8AXD1YGIDg&usg=AFQjCNG1I5DZzP8Fffd1hqVqtFsQCyM87A&bvm=bv.73231344,d.dGc) to set up the client side validation.

**Is there a way in the forms.py file in the "address_country_style_type = forms.TypedChoiceField" declaration to state that the address_country_style_type must not accept an option value of 0, so that this validation will be picked up automatically by django-parsley and I can cull the cleaned data if statement?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked with django, so I can only help you with parsleyjs.

Parsleyjs will tell you the field is required if you manage to remove the `value="0"` and place it like `value=""`:

```
<option value=""> Select a country or territory</option>
```